# Vagrant opening machine with command prompt how can we access in graphical mode

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, vagrantfile

When I execute command `Vagrant up` its opening `hashicorp/precise32` box in `command prompt mode` even I had mentioned `gui = true`.

Can we able to access this box/machine in `graphical mode/terminal` and if yes then what do need to configure.

**Vagrantfile** -

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"

  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
  config.vm.provision :chef_client do |chef|
    chef.provisioning_path = "/etc/chef"
    ... ...
    ... ...
  end

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
      vb.gui = true
      vb.cpus = 1
  end

end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this with the VirtualBox provider? Can we see your Vagrantfile?

Comment: updated with vagrantfile details and using VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

The base box that you're using is Ubuntu Server and does not have a desktop environment. So you'll need to install one...

Make sure you have the VirtualBox Extension Pack installed ([download here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)). Then update your Chef provisioning to install the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage and try a `vagrant provision` command (or `vagrant up` if your box isn't created yet). Provisioning is likely to take a while because Chef will be installing hundreds of packages. Alternatively you could install the `xfce4` metapackage instead of `ubuntu-desktop`. XFCE is **much** smaller. You may need to `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up` in order to get the GUI to launch.